# how to make spring-boot-starter-data-redis delete return result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

## Hi everyone,

I use spring-boot-starter-data-redis library .

And I am using the RedisTemplate to operate redis.I want to get the result of deleting the key.But I found that the funcation return void value.I read the code of how it works.And I find it return nothing.How can I get the delete result to know if it works right?
Please help me.

## Thanks! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`delete(Collection<K> keys`)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#delete-java.util.Collection-) on RedisTemplate returns a `Long` which is number of keys deleted. Which method returns `void`?

Comment: I search it and find it is void .Can you tell me your redis dependency with maven? please.